# Memcache get method throws IOException

Tags: java, memcached

When trying get in memcache client, getting the below excepton.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.fet.myclass.webservice.data.DataList
    at com.schooner.MemCached.ObjectTransCoder.decode(Unknown Source)
```

Please help. Thanks.

EDIT:

DataList is my own object. Is there any constraints like, only native java objects can be cached, like that?

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace. and what is DataList? and can you post its relevant code

Comment: DataList is my own object and set to memcache is working fine. when calling get method, it throws IOException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MemCached.ObjectTransCoder decode method rely on the [`java.io.ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to deserialize the cached Java objects from the cache.

So, first, you have to check that your DataList object is serializable. That is: it implements the `java.io.Serializable` interface, and also all its class level attributes are primitive types or serializable objects by themselves.

Also, reviewing the component code listed [here](http://www.suilink.com/trac/hrm/browser/third-party/java-memcached/src/main/java/com/schooner/MemCached/ObjectTransCoder.java) the decode methods are implemented in such a way that a ClassNotFoundException gets wrapped inside an IOExpcetion using the class name as its message, which seems to be happening here.

So, as a second point, you should check if the process where you are getting this error, has your class included at its classpath (via -cp argument, or whatever the case), and if the class name exposed at the error matches exactly you class full qualified name.